# Cypress assert API response with value that is generated in the API

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to assert that my api response contains one parameter that is generated in the api like an ID.
I am aware that i can't predict the value but it's possible to validate the type of the value?

For example my response payload is the following:

{
json: "request"
id: "TX8982XASA"
}

I want to assert the ID value.

To assert a return payload i use the following:

expect(response).to.have.property(key, value)

The response is the object that is returned from the API and the key = ID. In this case the value is "TX8982XASA" but since it's always generated i can't use it directly.

Comment: You can use match and then a regex, maybe this way your test is a bit more precise...

Comment: type of the value? so check its a string. if it must be a specific format then use https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectstringmatchingstring--regexp

Answer (score 3):

Two assertions seem appropriate to run in this instance - existence and typeof.

```js
// property exists
expect(response).to.have.property(key)
// or
expect(response).to.have.property('id')

// property has type
expect(typeof response[key]).to.eq('string')  // whatever type it is
// or
expect(typeof response.id).to.eq('number')
```